# When is a quotient map to an orbit space a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, closed-map

$\pi :X\to X/G $  where $G$ is a group acting on X and $X/G $ is the orbit space associated with this action. Does $\pi $ always take closed sets to closed sets? (or in other words is $\pi$ a closed map?)

Answer (score 4):

Let $G=\mathbb{R}$ act on $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ by translating along the second coordinate. That is,$$t(x,y)=(x,y+t).$$ The quotient space is $\mathbb{R}$, and the quotient map is projection on the first coordinate.

Let $S=\{xy=1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $S$ is closed, but its image is not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually knew that projection though a quotient map is not a closed map. But couldn't relate it to a group action.

Comment: One more question..Is it always possible to see a quotient space as an orbit space of some group action?

Comment: @Hili This may depend on your requirements from a group action. If, for example, you expect the group to act by homeomorphisms, I guess the answer to your question is no. Equivalence relations on topological spaces can by pretty wild.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.